# covariance of a Markov chain derivation (Kalman filter)

Tags: markov-chains, covariance, kalman-filter

I was reading about Kalman filter and want to derive some formulas. Namely, they consider a random process (I am omitting constant shift, since it is trivial)

$$x_{k+1} = {\bf F}_k x_k + v_k$$

where $x_k$ is value of a random vector at step $k$, ${\bf F}_k$ is non-random transition matrix and $v_k$ is a random noise vector.

I want to derive the formula for the covariance of $x_{k+1}$

$${\bf C}_{k+1} = {\rm cov}(x_{k+1}, x^T_{k+1})$$

The answer is

$${\bf C}_{k+1} = {\bf F}_k {\bf C}_k {\bf F}^T_k + {\bf Q}_k$$

where ${\bf Q}_k$ is the noise covariance vector.

$${\bf Q}_{k+1} = {\rm cov}(v_{k+1}, v^T_{k+1})$$

Can anybody please outline me the derivation of this formula or give a reference to such derivation (preferably more detailed)?

I have stumbled at the point of calculating the expectation $E(x_{k+1})$, because I am not sure how to deal with two sources of randomness -- from distribution of $x_k$ itself and from $v_k$.

I was thinking about using the classic formula for the distribution of $x_{k+1}$

$$p(x_{k+1}) = \int P(x_{k+1}|x_{k}) p(x_k)dx_k$$

and then find the expectation from this distribution. So, I wrote

$$P(x_{k+1}|x_{k}) = \delta(x_{k+1} - {\bf F}_k x_k - v_k)$$

Then

$$p(x_{k+1}) = \int \delta(x_{k+1} - {\bf F}_k x_k - v_k) p(x_k)dx_k$$

Without random contribution $v_k$ this would be simple transformation of variables with the result

$$p(x_{k+1}) = 
\frac{1}{|\det {\bf F}_k|}p({\bf F}^{-1}_k x_{k+1})$$

but I am not sure how to deal with the randov noise $v_k$ since it is an additional source of randomness...

Any help is appreciated (preferable detailed explanation of a method which should be used or a reference to a good book/paper/lecture notes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x_k $ and $v_k $ are independent,  it follow that
\begin{equation}
\text {cov}(x_{k+1},x_{k+1}^T) = {\bf F}_k \text {cov}(x_{k},x_{k}^T)  {\bf F}_k^T + \text {cov}(v_{k},v_{k}^T) 
\end{equation}

See the properties section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties (Bienaymé formula) and observe that it generalizes in a straightforward manner to the Covariance operator: "the covariance of the sum (or the difference) of uncorrelated random vectors is the sum of their covariances"

A good book on the subject of linear estimation and Kalman filters is: "[Linear Estimation](https://books.google.se/books/about/Linear_Estimation.html?id=zNJFAQAAIAAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y)" by Thomas Kailath, Ali Sayed, and Babak Hassibi.

---

Now regarding your computations above, observe that the mean of $x$ at any time depends on the assumption on the mean of the initial condition of $x$ and the means of the noise $v$. If $v$ has a zero mean for all $k$ and the initial condition $x_0$ has zero mean, then the state process has zero mean at any $k$. Note that you can write
\begin{equation}
x_{k+1} = ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots {\bf F}_{1}) x_0  + ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots{\bf F}_{2} )v_0 + ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots{\bf F}_{3}) v_1 + \dots + v_k
\end{equation} 
and therefore,

\begin{equation}\small
E[x_{k+1}] = ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots {\bf F}_{1}) E[x_0]  + ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots{\bf F}_{2} )E[v_0] + ({\bf F}_{k+1}{\bf F}_{k}\dots{\bf F}_{3}) E[v_1] + \dots + E[v_k]
\end{equation}

where the expectation operator here is with respect to all sources of randomness; that is with respect to the density
\begin{equation}
p(x_0, v_0, \dots, v_k).
\end{equation}

If you want to compute the density  $p(x_{k+1})$ you have to marginalize the joint density 
\begin{equation}
p(x_{k+1}, x_k, \dots, x_1, x_0) = p(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^{k+1} p(x_i|x_{i-1})
\end{equation}
in which
\begin{equation}
p(x_i |x_{i-1}) = p_{v_i}(x_i - {\bf F}_{i-1}x_{i-1})
\end{equation}
where $p_{v_i}$ denotes the probability density function of the random vector $v_{i}$.

Hope this clarifies it to you.

Comment: excellent answer, thanks!